# UserControl with a combobox and a listView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I have a Usercontrol that contains a ListView, Add Button and a ComboBox. The intention is that when a user clicks Add the selected item in the ComboBox is added to the ListView.

This functionality works fine, however it would be great if the item in the ComboBox was removed list as duplicates aren't allowed in the ListView. Currently I am handling this in the ViewModel, but that means I have to implement the same code for each instance of the UserControl

Does anyone have a good idea how to implement a generic solution for this problem?

```
<UserControl>

 <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListViewItemsSource}"
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind ListViewSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ItemTemplate="{x:Bind ListViewItemTemplate}"
                  Style="{x:Bind ListViewStyle}"
                  Margin="{StaticResource MediumBottomMargin}"
                  Visibility="{x:Bind ListViewVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <uwptoolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

        </ListView>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" 
                      Style="{StaticResource StandardComboStyleFixedWidth}"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboBoxItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectedItem="{x:Bind ComboBoxSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="{x:Bind ComboBoxDisplayMemberPath}"
                      PlaceholderText="{x:Bind ComboBoxPlaceholderText}"
                      BorderBrush="{x:Bind ComboBoxBorderBrush, Mode=TwoWay}">

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            </ComboBox>

            <Button x:Name="AddButton" 
                    Style="{StaticResource AddButtonStyle}" 
                    Click="AddButton_Click"
                    IsEnabled="{x:Bind AddButtonIsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

EDIT:

I should add that I didn't create this class, I have inherited it and am looking to improve it. I will implement the style changes suggested.

What I mean by code behind is this:

```
                <uc:ListTagControl                             
                               ComboBoxItemsSource="{x:Bind _viewModel.TypeItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               ComboBoxSelectedItem="{x:Bind _viewModel.SafetyType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               ComboBoxDisplayMemberPath="Type"
                               ListViewSelectedItem="{x:Bind _viewModel.SelectedListViewItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               ListViewItemsSource="{x:Bind _viewModel.Safeties, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               AddButtonOnClick="{x:Bind _viewModel.AddType}"
                               AddButtonIsEnabled="True" />
```

In the ViewModel it will then do this, to remove the item from the combobox:

```
        TypeItems.Remove(TypeItems
            .Where(i => i.Id == _Safety.SafetyType.Id).Single());
```

I want to move this as a generic implementation into the xaml.cs

Comment: You cant implement the removal in the Code Behind of your UserControl, if the change is only relevant to the UI and doesnt't have to be stored in the model. Writing Code Behind should be avoided in MVVM, but it's fine for Custom Controls, the Code Behind logic is only relevant to the UI.

Comment: Also, here are some hints: Having a single ColumnDefinition with Width="*" (take all available space) doesn't do anything an can be safely removed.

Comment: And, the StackPanel's default Orientation is Vertical, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: And if you are trying to use MVVM, don't use EventHandlers for controls since they create a strong link between your View and ViewModel, which should be loosely coupled, so they can be reuused. Use Commands instead.

Comment: I have slighted edited the question as I feel like my intention wasn't clear.

Comment: I just found a mistake in my first comment that's completely misleading. Of course I meant to write "You CAN implement..". So whats stopping you from removing the selected item from the item source on Click of your button? In Code Behind, you have full access to all controls of your view.

Comment: @Dustybin80: Why can't you simply remove the `ComboBoxSelectedItem` from `ComboBoxItemsSource` before you add it to `ListViewItemsSource`?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think for the most basic uses of the control that suggestion will work. However as the ListView and ComboBox items don't have to be of the same type it is more complex than I first appreciated. The ComboBox items are actually the data used to construct the ListView items in a lot of cases.

Comment: I am confused about  this line *however it would be great if the item in the ComboBox was removed list as duplicates aren't allowed in the ListView.* could you explain it.

Comment: The 'comboBoxItemsSource' is the list of options a user can choose from. When an item is selected and they click the add button. An item is added to the 'listViewItemSource' collection. The way the control is used in the project they shouldn't be allowed to add the same option twice. Therefore hiding (or removing) the option from the comboBox is better than the current solution which is to just block the action. @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: So you want to remove the same items from the comboBox is better then add them to the listview right?

Comment: Yes, my initial thought was to just bind both lists to the same collection and use visibility. However some very strange things have been done with data structures by the original dev and this isn't possible.

Comment: For this, you could compare the source  ComboBox and ListView and remove the same items before add to ListView.